# google OAuth login for google Apps Script webapps

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth

i have developed a google appscript webapp to which i want to add a login using google id option.
the web is based on appscript.
 the html portion is also on appscript. 
After going through the instruction on the guide page of google oauth i am completely confused.
google OAuth is needed only for getting the users details i.e. email id , name etc

Comment: When deploying the Web App in Google Apps Script, under Execute the app as: choose user accessing the web app

Comment: @Hassan  what if mail and other services are used in the webapp

Comment: It will use the Users Gmail account.

Comment: @hassan not helpful. It will look forward to create all the services in the users account again

Comment: Hi there @tinkershukla! I don't understand what do you mean by «*It will look forward to create all the services in the users account again*», could you please explain it to me?

Comment: When a user accesses the webapp from his/her Gmail Id the script will ask for access for Google services to execute script by calling the services and creating other resources like Google sheets calendar etc

Comment: Hi @tinkershukla! It is not clear to me where you are encountering an issue. If you want to add a Google logging into your Apps Script web-app you can follow [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) guide. Please, tell us all where you have any doubt or just share your code so we all can take a look.

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron this is my problem
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The JavaScript origin in the request, https://n-tk3g6s4u5jztr6tiwt4qn2j5ze3taoymlgdpaci-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. Visit https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/854388979505-uns0sg4ehihacgf4oemrafiln2269m7n.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=854388979505 to update the authorized JavaScript origins.

I am trying to embed this into a google webapp

Answer (score 1):

Based on your last comment, I see that you got the error «*Error: redirect_uri_mismatch The JavaScript origin in the request,  [n-tk3g6s4u5jztr6tiwt4qn2j5ze3taoymlgdpaci-0lu-script.googleuser…](https://n-tk3g6s4u5jztr6tiwt4qn2j5ze3taoymlgdpaci-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/), does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. Visit  [console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/…](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/854388979505-uns0sg4ehihacgf4oemrafiln2269m7n.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=854388979505)  to update the authorized JavaScript origins*». This error appears because you are using a [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) not authorized by your current OAuth credentials. You can easily solve that error with the following steps.

#### PROCEDURE

1. Open a new browser tab and go to [Credentials](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) on your APIs & Services menu.
2. Select your project on the top bar.
3. On the *OAuth 2.0 Client IDs* menu you will find your authorized URIs. If you click on each name, you will see its associated URI. Your URI should match any of them for your web-app to work. Click on the name of any credential under *OAuth 2.0 Client IDs* to continue.
4. Modify the URI under *URIs* (or add a different one clicking `+Add URI`).
5. Click on `Save`.

Now your URI will be authorised and, as a result, you won't encounter the same error. This configuration will be effective in some minutes, but sometimes it could last longer. Don't hesitate to write me back with any additional question.

Comment: what should be the uri for an appscript webapp

Comment: You should use the URI of the JavaScript root. That is, the URI of the server that hosts your web-app. When required to login a user, that server will send a request to Google servers. If the request comes from the whitelisted URI as detailed above, the petition will be accepted.

Comment: how can one get the Google appscript servers root uri

Comment: Based on your error message, you are using the following JavaScrip origin URI: `https://n-tk3g6s4u5jztr6tiwt4qn2j5ze3taoymlgdpaci-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/`. You can add that one to the whitelist if you plan to keep using it.

Comment: thanks for the help . I am thru the sign-in debacle but somehow the redirect uri is not working

Comment: Hi @tinkershukla! With the former steps you can configure origin and redirect URIs. It is not clear to me what is your issue, could you please clarificate it for me?

Comment: The link which we get after publish as webapp is not working when used in redirect uri

Comment: Hi there @tinkershukla! When you say that it is not working, what is problematic behaviour? I am interested in knowing what message appears when trying to open the link. Also, to not miss anything, are you opening the link with the same account that published the web-app?